# Can anyone help me with the regex for the following example?

Tags: python, regex, split

Sample Data:

```
"PlayerId":169193,"PlayerName":"Alexandre Lacazette","PlaysOnHomeTeam":true,"OptaId":"p59966","GoalsConcededInBox":1,"ShotsInsideBox":8,"ShotsWoodwork":1,"TotalPasses":31,"PassSuccess":23,"KeyPasses":5,"DribblesAttempted":3,"DribblesWon":2,"AerialsWon":5,"AerialsLost":2,"TacklesSuccess":3,"TacklesAttempted":3
```

what i want is a list with data which is inside the quotes i.e 
PlayerId
PlayerName
PlaysOnHomeTeam
OptaId
..
..
..

Can anyone tell me the regex to achieve this

Comment: It looks like a dict , if so you can take all the keys ..

Comment: Do you want `PlayerId` or `169193`?

Comment: No it is string

Comment: @MasOOd.KamYab PlayerId

Comment: Looks like JSON. Is it surrounded with `{}` braces?

Comment: It is a string sir I just want the data i.e inside the quote

Comment: I understand it's a string, but it looks like a JSON formatted string. Sure you can write a regex to parse it, but if it's valid JSON you're better off parsing that using the bulit-in JSON utilities in python.

Comment: Do you want "p59966"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this:

`,?"(\w+)":`

explanation:

`,?` is said it took 0 or 1 of `,`

`"` before the sentences.

`(\w+)` is what u want. It is the word character `a-zA-Z0-9_`

`"` after the sentences

[example](https://regexr.com/3ouoi)

Comment: \w is not some character, it is word character a-zA-Z0-9_

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the left-hand string for each pair:

```
import json
s = '{'+ '''"PlayerId":169193,"PlayerName":"Alexandre Lacazette","PlaysOnHomeTeam":true,"OptaId":"p59966","GoalsConcededInBox":1,"ShotsInsideBox":8,"ShotsWoodwork":1,"TotalPasses":31,"PassSuccess":23,"KeyPasses":5,"DribblesAttempted":3,"DribblesWon":2,"AerialsWon":5,"AerialsLost":2,"TacklesSuccess":3,"TacklesAttempted":3''' + '}'
list(json.loads(s))
```

Output:

```
['PlayerId', 'PlayerName', 'PlaysOnHomeTeam', 'OptaId', 'GoalsConcededInBox', 'ShotsInsideBox', 'ShotsWoodwork', 'TotalPasses', 'PassSuccess', 'KeyPasses', 'DribblesAttempted', 'DribblesWon', 'AerialsWon', 'AerialsLost', 'TacklesSuccess', 'TacklesAttempted']
```